# Vagrant VM and auto-starting Ruby on Rails Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, vagrant

Our team is just starting to experiment with Vagrant as a way to manage our development environment across a very diverse team (multiple developers, designers, UX engineers and stakeholders), so it seems like the perfect solution for us.

Due to the diversity of the team, I would prefer to be able to avoid the part of the Vagrant process where the user needs to SSH into the VM in order to start the server. I know that it's possible to edit the startup files (We're using Ubuntu as the VM base) for the VM, and also that it's possible to edit Vagrant plugins, and based on what I'm reading, it appears that both possible solutions can give us the desired activity. What I don't know is what's considered the best practice for this problem. I'm very new to the Vagrant space, so I'm reaching out in the hopes that someone can provide insight as to what the best way to accomplish this goal is.

Or, if anyone knows of a reusable example of how to accomplish this goal that's floating around, that would be appreciated as well.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up simply writing Vagrant plugins right inside our Vagrantfile for the project. Perhaps not the best way, but effective for our personal situation.